# Best Practices when inserting edges and vertices

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

**Given**

I've to insert a hughe set of data into neo4j. Currently I created methods for

a) Insert a batch of nodes

```
 public Task AddNodesAsync<T>(List<T> nodes)
        {
            return client.Cypher.Create("(n:" + typeof(T).Name + " {nodes})").WithParams(new
            {
                nodes
            }).ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
        }
```

b) Related 2 Kind of nodes

```
 public async Task LinkVertices<TSource, TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget, bool>> join, string relationName)
    {
        string sourceName = typeof(TSource).Name;
        string targetName = typeof(TTarget).Name;


            await client.Cypher
                .Match(string.Format("({0}:{0})", sourceName), string.Format("({0}:{0})", targetName))
                .Where(join)
                .Create(string.Format("{0}-[:{2}]->{1}", sourceName, targetName, relationName))
                .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();

    }
```

Now I call `AddNodesAsync<T>` 2 Times and after that i call the second method to link them. Likethis:

```
AddNodesAsync(Projects);
AddNodesAsync(myCustomers);

LinkVertices<Projects,Customer>((project,customer) => project.customerId == customer.id,"projectsOfCustomer");
```

This works fine but i', asking my self if this is a good solution.
I can see that especially the linking process is very slow.

**So my question is**

What is the recommended way for an initialization of neo4j ?

Show I Use the C# Api ? The restfull api ? Or event the csv importer?
And second question is there a way to insert both batches with the links in one step ? I would expected this may be faster.

Comment: Batching the updates into a single transaction will result in a substantial increase in performance, as will creating indexes on :Label(property) also helps when there's a need to lookup a node to create a relationship.

Comment: So I just need to start a transaction ? If i remember right i had a exception that there is no create allowed.. hmm maybe i'm worng? Can you provide an example so i can check what i had made differently?

Comment: And Further more there is no syntax t ocreate 2 nodes with a link in one commant is it ?

Comment: I'm not a java guy so you'll need to research this - the protocol is to start a TX, create your nodes and relationships, and then tell cypher to commit the TX. Cypher also supports creating multiple nodes in a single statement - it's just a series of CREATE() statements one after the other. As for how you do that - you'll need to find that in the docs for the driver.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the [Import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html) if you want to quickly import a huge amount of data into a brand new neo4j DB.